# Javascript OTA call to HP QC

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor, hp-quality-center

I found below OTA method to access HP QC , but when I execute it I am getting "sys is not a defined" error. I am using Protractor(Nodejs) to test an application thus I need to use JavaScript to do OTA calls

Can someone please help me with this

```
function QualityCenterTest()
{
var qc = Sys.OleObject("TDApiOle80.TDConnection");
//var qc = qcc.TDConnection;
qcConnectionPath_String = " http://qc/qcbin /";
qcDomain_String = "Abc";
qcProject_String = "xyz";
qcUserId_String = "Test";
qcPassword_String = "";
qc.InitConnectionEx(qcConnectionPath_String);
qc.Login(qcUserId_String, qcPassword_String);
qc.Connect(qcDomain_String, qcProject_String);
// Set the folder
var currTestFolder = qc.TestSetTreeManager.NodeByPath("Root\\abc ");
var testParam = " TestSet";
var testSetList= currTestFolder.FindTestSets(testParam);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe `Sys.OleObject` is a COM object for Windows environments only and Node.js does not come with support for this out of the box.

https://helloacm.com/using-com-object-in-nodejs/

> However, the NodeJS does not inherently support the Win32 COM/OLE
>   techniques maybe because it is designed to be platform independent in
>   the first place, like Python, which is similar in the case that you
>   will need to download the win32com package [see here].

If you need to run your app on Windows to get access to HP QA, you probably need something like the package mentioned above

https://github.com/idobatter/node-win32ole

Please provide more information about your environment and what other tools you might be using.

(Also, I am looking into HP QC integrations as well, so please provide some more information about the process you are using)

**more information**
Maybe you could try the REST API instead of the COM object.
http://alm-help.saas.hpe.com/en/Latest/api_refs/REST_TECH_PREVIEW/ALM_REST_API_TP.html

Comment: The REST API inherently has limited functional support as compared to the _TDApiOle80.TDConnection_ COM object. The best way to effectively run the COM object is via .NET languages like VBScript or C#.